# Move SearchBar up when active

Tags: objective-c, uisearchbar

Currently I have a searchbar placed at the centre of my view. I was wondering if there was a way to have it move up to the top of the view when it's active and then move back when it's not.

Any help?

Comment: put the search bar in scroll view and use keyboard delegate methods to move it up and down

Answer (score 0):

Add the  below KeyBoard observer notifications into `ViewWillAppear`

```
 [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(keyboardWillShow:) name:UIKeyboardWillShowNotification object:nil];
 [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(keyboardWillHide:) name:UIKeyboardWillHideNotification object:nil];
```

In KeyboardWillShow, move the search bar to top

```
-(void)keyboardWillShow:(NSNotification*)sender
{
  //Move search bar to top 
  self.searchBar.frame=CGRectMake(0, 10, self.searchBar.frame.size.width, self.searchBar.frame.size.height);
}
```

In KeyBoardWillHide, move the search to center

```
-(void)keyboardWillHide:(NSNotification*)sender
{
  //Move search bar to center
 self.searchBar.frame=CGRectMake(0, self.view.frame.size.height/2, self.searchBar.frame.size.width, self.searchBar.frame.size.height);

}
```

In `ViewWillDisappear`, remove the keyboard observer

```
 [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]removeObserver:self name:UIKeyboardWillHideNotification object:nil];
 [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]removeObserver:self name:UIKeyboardWillShowNotification object:nil];
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! when moving, should I use co-ordinates? An example would be perfect. Sorry I'm getting to grips with this!

Comment: @PrateekBiyani Yes! you have to change coordinated, the above answer is edited just to give a simple scenario.

Comment: Thank you! I tried this inside a scrollview as you suggested and when I click away from the searchbar it just vanishes! So then I moved the searchbar out of the scrollview and it doesn't move :/ It makes an animation when I click away but not really anything new :/

Comment: No need to place search bar in scroll view. Above code  simply moves the frame of searchbar. When keyboard appears, it moves top and when disappear it moves center. I have edited the keyboardWillHide(), self.view.frame.size.height/2 has been assigned to y. Try this.

Comment: Thanks for keeping on trying! I tried this out of the scrollview and it does nothing :/ Even with the edit. The search just works as normal and no movement :/

Comment: Okay did a bit more research. I have been using this cline `[self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:NO animated:animated];` to hide the nav bar. This was stopping any animation whatsoever. When I comment this out, the searchbar animates BUT it doesn't do what it is supposed to. What happens is - I click on the searchbar, it remains in the same position and then when I click OFF it, it suddenly flashes out of position and returns back.

Comment: In normal case, it should work, as it is just changing y when keyboard appears and disapper. Check  if you have overridden any property. Sometimes UISearchBar behaves little wierd!!!

Comment: Hmm I'll have a look. This is really racking my brain!

Comment: AHA! It has something to do with the fact the search bar is linked up to a search display controller. Is there someway to modify the code so it will work in this scenario too?