# Searchbar vanishes in UIScrollview

Tags: uiscrollview, uisearchbar

I have a searchbar present in a uisearchview. When I click on the search and then cancel it, the searchbar suddenly vanishes from the scrollview.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

check the UISearchBar frame before search and after it. I think you have some problems with layout...

Comment: How should I do that? When I move the searchbar out of the scrollview then it works perfectly fine :/

Comment: use breakpoints and debugger to print out frame value, or NSLog

Comment: Okay I will try. My problem relates to this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23195242/move-searchbar-up-when-active